# Is it possible to Fetch Real-time data using Riot Valorant Api?

Tags: riot-games-api

I am making an application that shows real-time status for a  Valorant game. like players alive, the type of weapons each play has, time remaining, etc.

Is it possible to use Riot Valorant API to do this for live matches or for previously played matches?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge you couldn't. But I think you should try with **Riot Games**' official production API, not development API.
Let me know if you find something relatable.

Comment: @tenoob found anything useful ?

Answer (score 1):

(This is adding onto Sanskar's answer, which I cannot comment on as I lack the required 'reputation')

I'm aware that this is an old question, but for anyone who happens to have stumbled upon this question, there is no way to obtain real-time in-game events however, there is a way to retrieve certain data from a match-- only except, not in an official way that does go against Riot Game's TOS of using third party software. Though, I wouldn't worry about this too much as long as you do not ruin the competitive integrity of the game by providing yourself with an in-game advantage over others in the game. I personally have been using this for over a year now and have not received any form of punishment for doing so.

Anyhow, back to the actual question of this thread, check out this document of API endpoints that have been scraped through monitoring HTTP traffic of the Riot Client. https://github.com/techchrism/valorant-api-docs/tree/trunk/docs/ You'll need to obtain certain authorization tokens of the Valorant account through whatever methods are available to you (I pray that it is through lawful means :) ), which highly depends on the type of endpoint. There are certain wrappers for these endpoints already made by other users somewhere on GitHub, and you can always ask for help in the small community of developers that are using these endpoints in the README of the GitHub page I sent in this post.

**REMEMBER TO NOT DO ANYTHING THAT WOULD CREATE AN UNFAIR ADVANTAGE, OR ANYTHING ELSE THAT A RIOT EMPLOYEE WOULD NOT APPROVE OF USING THIS :)**